# jQuery/Javascript If Data Count Is Greater Than

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "Like" button on my site. It applies the likes to a data-count attribute.

```
<span class="count" data-count="5">5</span>
```

How Do I access that data count through jQuery/Javascript.

I am trying to do a "If .count[data-count] > 5 .addClass.

So every time that data-count goes over 5, I add a class to the span.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(function(){
     $(".count").each(function(){
           var a = $(this).data("count");
           var b = parseInt(a);
           if(b>5){
              $(this).addClass("dd");
           }
      });

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z1qotub4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var elem = $('.count');
if(Number(elem.attr('data-count')) > 5){
  elem.addClass('someclass');
}
```

You could also use `elem.data(count)` and remove the `Number` part.

Comment: Can't you just do .data('count') as a shortcut for accessing data attributes?